# Customizing bower packages

Tags: javascript, git, github, bower

I am using several open source js libraries in my project. I recently moved to use bower for all the front-end dependencies. I liked how I can just provide a github url instead of a proper package name.

I have customized few libraries. So to manage them using bower, I created a single private repository called `myLibs` in an organization account on Github.

I am creating branches for each customized library. For example, customized `angular-bootstrap` library will be in `angular-bootstrap` branch and customized `angular-material` library will be in `angular-material` branch.

Now I am creating tags for each release in each library. The naming convention that I am using is `branch-name/x.y.z` For example, I have `angular-bootstrap/1.0.0` and `angular-material/1.1.1` tags.

This was good till I had to install these libraries using bower. To install the custom libraries I called the following command (It's a dummy url, don't try it)

```
bower install --save-exact library-patch=https://github.com/test_org/myLibs.git#branch-name/1.0.0
```

The library gets installed and I can see it in bower_components too, but in my bower.json the dependency entry turns up like this -

```
"library-patch":"https://github.com/test_org/myLibs.git#undefined"
```

This is not what I wanted. I wanted to have the proper tag name to be saved. I don't want to manually make changes in the `bower.json` file every time I want to add a custom library.

My first thought was that the naming convention of the tags will be a problem. So I changed it to `branch-name-x.y.z` from `branch-name/x.y.z which allowed me to have the exact version in the bower.json to install it properly, but when trying to install the libraries using the terminal, instead of using bower.json, I am getting the`#undefined` tag in the end of the dependencies.

Here's the log I am getting while installing the library from terminal.

```
bower install --save-exact library-patch=https://github.com/test_org/myLibs.git#branch-name-1.0.0
bower not-cached    https://github.com/test_org/myLibs.git#branch-name-1.0.0
bower resolve       https://github.com/test_org/myLibs.git#branch-name-1.0.0
bower download      https://github.com/test_org/myLibs/archive/branch-name-1.0.0.tar.gz
bower retry         Download of https://github.com/test_org/myLibs/archive/branch-name-1.0.0.tar.gz failed with EHTTP, trying with git..
bower checkout      library-patch#branch-name-1.0.0
bower resolved      https://github.com/test_org/myLibs.git#branch-name-1.0.0
bower install       library-patch#branch-name-1.0.0

library-patch#branch-name-1.0.0 bower_components/library-patch
└── angular#1.4.8
```

Why am I getting undefined in the release/tag name? Am I making any mistake while naming the tags? Is there any way I can install those custom libs from terminal and save the exact tag in bower.json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for the problem was to use `--save` instead of `--save-exact`. I have no explanation for the same right now, but I'll update the answer as soon as I can.

As far as I can tell, it's because the package was getting installed from github directly, instead of from bower registry.